# deploy a simple function to amazon sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have been playing with Amazon Sagemaker. They have amazing sample notebooks in different areas. However, for testing purposes, I want to create an endpoint that returns the result from a function. From what I have seen so far, my understanding is that we can deploy only models but I would like to clarify it.

Let's say I want to invoke the endpoint and it should give me the square of the input value. So, I will first create a function:

```
def my_square(x):
    return x**2
```

Can we deploy this simple function in Amazon Sagemaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible but it will need some overhead:
You can pass your own docker images for training and inference to sagemaker.

Inside this containers you can do anything you want including return your `my_square` function. Keep in mind that you have to write your own flask microservice including proxy and wsgi server(if needed).

In my opinion [this example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb) is the most helpfull one.